# Is it possible in VS Code to debug with arguments, but without explicit launch configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In order to debug a Python script with command line arguments in VS Code, (at least as far as I know) one needs to create a launch configuration, naming all these arguments there, and run the debugger for that configuration. This is, however, a bit cumbersome when I write a bunch of small scripts, so that I would need to create a new launch configuration with all these command line arguments for each such script.

So is there a way to run and debug a script with command line arguments, but without creating a new launch configuration first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`${input}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) variables to create a generic launch config with N arguments